# Javascript: Better way to read associated arrays

Tags: javascript

I have this array named *values* with objects in it

```js
let values = [
{name: "firstname", value: "Mike"},

{name: "lastname", value: "Smith "},

{name: "emailaddress", value: "mike@test.com"},

{name: "role", value: "123"}]


// Then I have code like this, which works

let editUser = {
    "firstnameofperson": values[0].value,
    "lastnameofperson": values[1].value,
    "emailaddress": values[2].value,
    "roleofperson": values[3].value,
}

console.log(editUser);
```

Is there a better way of doing this, rather than specifying array *values[x]* indexes etc.

I'm working with ES6 btw

Comment: `with json objects in it` - no such thing as a json object ... there is no json in your code, it's just an array of objects

Comment: yes sorry , my typing error, I'll edit

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "no such thing as a json object". I am genuinely asking, because of this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: Or do you just mean in his code?

Comment: w3schools is a poor joke - http://www.json.org/

Comment: They are talking about objects as well.

Comment: anything `w3schools` says is not worth the bits used to store it, nor the time required to read it

Comment: I said, json.org are talking about objects as well.

Comment: @Rory There is such a thing as a [*JSON object*](http://www.json.org/); however, JSON is a text serialization format that *represents* an object graph (which can be expressed as JavaScript objects). This code shows *JavaScript Object Literal syntax* (including JavaScript expressions which are invalid in JSON) that evaluates to JavaScript objects/values when executed; just because JSON "looks like some JavaScript" does not make JavaScript == JSON.. so if there is no `JSON.parse(stringOfJSON)`, then it's probably *not* JSON.

Comment: No, that is not what those are either. For those to be object literals to be used for JSON the properties would have to be in quotes, e.g. { "a" : "b" }. As it stands this is merely an array of object literals that have nothing to do with JSON whatsoever. At the same time the statement "there is no such thing as JSON objects" by @JaromandaX  is plain false, because when a JSON string is deserialized via JSON.parse a JavaScript JSON object is exactly what we get.

Comment: To clarify @user2864740: You're right about what you say, except that '{ a : "b" }' is not a string that can be successfully processed by JSON.parse. ;)

Comment: @KVNSTOBJEKT It was not the goal to imply that all JavaScript Object Literals (or this case in particular) would be valid JSON :-)

Comment: I didn't say it was. Read carefully.

Comment: Oh well, I think we cleared everything up. Bottom line, there is no JSON in the code above, but there is such a thing as JSON objects in general, which are objects generated from a valid JSON string via JSON.parse. :)

Comment: It's interesting. But I think the important point, for @Rory, is to understand that `json object`, here, has no meaning. There are javascript objects, nothing less, nothing more. I think he understood now, thanks to you ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way of doing this could be:

*(Mind: 'emailaddressofperson', not 'emailaddress', but it's a matter of coherence, you should change the property name according to this answer — even remove the 'ofperson' suffix)*

```js
let arr = [
    { name: "firstname"    , value: "Mike"          }
  , { name: "lastname"     , value: "Smith "        }
  , { name: "emailaddress" , value: "mike@test.com" }
  , { name: "role"         , value: "123"           }
]
  
let editUser = {};

arr.forEach( x => editUser[x.name+'ofperson'] = x.value )

console.log(editUser);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks, that'll do nicely, I've upped your reply. The code I've been given is far more complicated than I wrote here. But this has given me a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your array as follows .

```js
var values=[];

values["firstname"]={name: "firstname", value: "Mike"};
values["lastname"]={name: "lastname", value: "Smith "};
values["emailaddress"]={name: "emailaddress", value: "mike@test.com"};
values["role"]={name: "role", value: "123"};
    
console.log(values["firstname"].value);
```

Comment: Hi @Pawan_sasanka, do you really think it's "a better way of doing this" as asking the question?… Congratulations for effort, though! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In that cases I usually use a transformation function.

For your example it could be:

```
function translate (d) {
    let p={};
    d.map(r=>p[r.name]=r.value);
    return p;
}
```

If you prefer an inliner:

```
let output = ((d)=>{let p={};d.map(r=>p[r.name]=r.value);return p})([
    {name: "firstname", value: "Mike"},
    {name: "lastname", value: "Smith "},
    {name: "emailaddress", value: "mike@test.com"},
    {name: "role", value: "123"}
]);
```

But, unless you just need to transform single item, for the sake of readability, I would prefer first approach and, in that case, I would prefer your version (I figure out that it is not the case).

Answer (score 0):

There is an ES6 object called [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) that holds key:value pairs, and has a way of getting values to you by using .get. This is different from your object, but another way of doing it.

```
//your data
let data = [{
    name: "firstname",
    value: "Mike"
  },

  {
    name: "lastname",
    value: "Smith "
  },

  {
    name: "emailaddress",
    value: "mike@test.com"
  },

  {
    name: "role",
    value: "123"
  }
];

//turn the data into their own arrays for the map object
let newArr = data.map((i) => [i.name, i.value]);
//create the map object
let testMap = new Map(newArr);
//shows the map obj
console.log(testMap)
  /*
  0 :{"firstname" => "Mike"}
  1 :{"lastname" => "Smith "}
  2 :{"emailaddress" => "mike@test.com"}
  3 :{"role" => "123"}
  */
  //an example of getting the firstname
  console.log(testMap.get("firstname")); //returns "Mike"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let values = [
  {name: "firstname", value: "Mike"},
  {name: "lastname", value: "Smith "},
  {name: "emailaddress", value: "mike@test.com"},
  {name: "role", value: "123"}
]

const newPropNames = [
  "firstnameofperson",
  "lastnameofperson",
  "emailaddress",
  "roleofperson",
]

const newValues = values
  .map((o,i) => ({ [newPropNames[i]]: o.value }))
  .reduce(((acc, nv) => Object.assign(acc, nv)), {})
```